# Can i use pointer arithmetic with Heap Functions to store arrays?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, desktop

I'm **very new** to C and i am trying to understand some notions about memory concepts. I already took a look at basic pointer functionality and wanted to try and make a function that calculates quadratic functions. The problem is that i needed my function to return an array (for result x1 and x2), and since that's not possible in C, i was left with heaps and poiners. I built this code and it works just fine but since C is so complex i wanted a second (or a third, fourth :D) opinion on this, **specifically** at the `HeapAlloc` and `*result_ptr` pointer arithmetic.

Is this correct? Can it cause any problem? Or is this the right way to do it? I honestly dont have any clue, all i know is that it works for now.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <heapapi.h>

float * bhaskara_heap(float a, float b, float c, HANDLE SysHeap){ // Returns the pointer for where the result is stored
    float delta = sqrt((b * b) - (4 * (a * c)));

    float divisor = 2 * a;

    float plus_x = ((-1 * b) + delta) / 2;
    float minus_x = ((-1 * b) - delta) / 2;

    /**
     * @brief Here, i use a pre-defined Handle to allocate 8 bytes (2 floats * 4 bytes),
     * then, i fill the address with the first value and the next one (ptr + 1) with the other value
    */
    float *result_ptr = HeapAlloc(SysHeap, HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, 8);

    *result_ptr = plus_x;
    *(result_ptr + 1) = minus_x;
    return result_ptr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    float a = atof(argv[1]);
    float b = atof(argv[2]);
    float c = atof(argv[3]);

    /**
     * @brief Creates a Heap in the virtual memory space,
     * with a min-size of 512 bytes, and dynamic max-size
    */
    HANDLE SysHeap = HeapCreate(HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, 512, 0);

    float *test = bhaskara_heap(a, b, c, SysHeap); // Calculates the quadratic function and store results in the defined memory space

    printf("O endereço de result_ptr é: %x\nE o de result_ptr + 1 é: %x\n", test,(test + 1));
    printf("O valor de result_ptr é: %f\n", *test);

    HeapFree(SysHeap, 0, test); // Here, i free the memory before "displaying" the last result, for test purposes

    printf("O segundo valor de result_ptr é: %f\n", *(test+1));

    HeapDestroy(SysHeap); // Destroys the heap and ends the proccess
    return(0);
}```
````

Comment: Kindly provide the code in text form and not image form. We have to constantly zoom in and out in the image and also we cannot try out the code when given as image.

Comment: please either tag C or C++. Not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that i needed my function to return an array (for result x1 and x2), and since that's not possible in C

The solution is to return a struct:

```
struct QuadraticSolution {
  _Complex double x1;
  _Complex double x2;
};

struct QuadraticSolution solveQuadraticEquation(double a, double b, double c) {
  // ... calculate x1 and x2 ... 
  struct QuadraticSolution res = {x1, x2};
  return res;
}
```